# How to install WireGuard on Orange Pi 4B?

Tags: debian, installation, wireguard

I want to make minecraft server to play with my friends and I need to connect my Orange Pi to WireGuard server, because it's located under the NAT (if I get that term right). But when I try to `apt install wireguard`, it also installs linux kernel:

```sh
orangepi@orangepi4:~$ sudo apt install wireguard
[sudo] password for orangepi:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  linux-image-5.10.0-27-rt-arm64 linux-image-rt-arm64 wireguard-tools
Suggested packages:
  linux-doc-5.10 debian-kernel-handbook
Recommended packages:
  firmware-linux-free apparmor
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-image-5.10.0-27-rt-arm64 linux-image-rt-arm64 wireguard wireguard-tools
0 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 27 not upgraded.
Need to get 44.8 MB of archives.
After this operation, 252 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
Abort.
orangepi@orangepi4:~$
```

---

When I first tried to apply WireGuard config, it said about unknown device type (haven't exact message). I searched about it and thoguht it's because of kernel modules weren't applied. After reboot I was unable to connect to my Orange Pi by SSH. I reinstalled system and tried to install WireGuard again. Now I saw it tried to install kernel 6.x and thought it might be the reason of Orange Pi to be "dead". I found mistake in `/etc/apt/sources.list` and changed it:

```
-deb http://mirror.docker.ru/debian/ stable main contrib non-free-firmware
+deb http://mirror.docker.ru/debian/ bullseye main contrib non-free
```

I installed wireguard, because saw now it has almost the same kernel version. But after realizing `modprobe` doesn't want to apply new module, I removed it. Here is kernels I had after installing:

```sh
orangepi@orangepi4:/boot$ dpkg --list | grep linux-image
ii  linux-image-5.10.0-27-rt-arm64        5.10.205-2                      arm64        Linux 5.10 for 64-bit ARMv8 machines, PREEMPT_RT (signed)
ii  linux-image-current-rk3399            3.0.6                           arm64        Linux kernel, version 5.10.43 # <-- that one is which I had in the start
ii  linux-image-rt-arm64                  5.10.205-2                      arm64        Linux for 64-bit ARMv8 machines (meta-package)
orangepi@orangepi4:/boot$ sudo find /boot/ -iname "vmlinuz*"
/boot/vmlinuz-5.10.43 # <-- that one is which I had in the start
/boot/vmlinuz-5.10.0-27-rt-arm64
```

I think after rebooting my Orange Pi could become "dead" again and removed WireGuard with kernels.

So how can I install wireguard on my Orange Pi 4B? Or should I use other solutions like OpenVPN?

---

Here's some additional information, which might be useful:

```sh
orangepi@orangepi4:~$ uname -a
Linux orangepi4 5.10.43 #3.0.6 SMP Mon Aug 1 18:31:02 CST 2022 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

Debian image: [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mFsVxuS75iBjLF8SoZ5yd-q1tnRSUkvG/view?usp=drive_link)

Orange Pi 4B downloads section: [orangepi.org](http://www.orangepi.org/html/hardWare/computerAndMicrocontrollers/service-and-support/Orange-pi-4-B.html)

Comment: "I installed wireguard, because saw now it has almost the same kernel version. " - What?  Can you please clarify? Can't verify the contents of [this](https://openvpn.net/vpn-server-resources/install-openvpn-access-server-on-raspberry-pi/) tutorial but it should be appliciable.

Comment: @Ramhound The OP actually aborted the installation, at least the first time.

Comment: @Ramhound I mean when I saw it is going to install `linux-image-5.10.0-27-rt-arm64` I thought it wouldn't make problems, because current kernel has version `5.10.43`, but when I saw `modprobe` can't apply module, I understood that something is going wrong

Comment: @ChanganAuto first codeblock is just showing what `apt` is going to install. Actually I installed WireGuard, but couldn't access Orange Pi after reboot

Comment: @DMax - Umm, it actually downgraded the kernel?  That is odd.

Comment: You should always fully update the OS - `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade` *before* installing any new software. And, again, folow the instructions above. Also when asking post what you did and the results and not what you didn't do.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I updated before installing new soft, but just `upgrade`, not `full-upgrade` (they don't have much difference if I got it right). I'm not an expert or even junior in it, I don't know what can happen, that's why I came here. I think if kernels were different in first case and that is what caused my orange to become "dead", I sure don't want to repeat that action again. Please, help me to change my post and make it more informative

Comment: @Ramhound I checked link, which you sent, and that's not what I need. Preferabley, I want to connect OPi to my already existing WIreGuard VPN. When I said "Or should I use other solutions like OpenVPN?" I meant that if problem is unsolvable, then tell me about alternatives.

Comment: @DMax - I am confused. A tutorial on how to install OpenVPN isn’t what you need?

Comment: @Ramhound - No, tutorial how to setup OpenVPN is not what I need. My question is in the title of the post

Comment: @DMax - I promise I read your question. You installed WireGuard and that downgraded the kernel. So you asked, “should I use other solutions like OpenVPN?”, so I provided a tutorial on how to install it.  I assume SSHing into this device is the only way to access it, and that determining the state of the machine after the kernel downgrade, is impossible. Specifically hooking it to a HDMI display.

Comment: @Ramhound - Sorry for late response, I was sleeping. Yes, currently, SSH is only the way to get OPi state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved my question. Firstly I tried to install `wireguard` ignoring mismatch of kernels, but that was unsuccessful. I found HDMI cable and tested if Orange Pi can load or it is just troubles with network. Sadly, it was first case.

I guess there are no easy ways to install WireGuard to Debian image that I gave in post. I wanted to build WireGuard myself, but didn't find `linux-headers` for it's kernel. So I just replaced Debian with Armbian image for [Orange Pi 4](https://www.armbian.com/orange-pi-4/). At the beginning I thought it woudln't work, because in my opinion Orange Pi 4 is not equal to Orange Pi 4B, but unexpectedly for me it did!

Armbian has some script to install wireguard automatically (I think [that](https://github.com/complexorganizations/wireguard-manager) is it). So I just run it, agreed with all questions and after removed configs, replacing it my own. Here's the commands I used (all of them were run as `root`):

```sh
wireguard-manager
# here would be much questions to setup Orange Pi as server

wg-quick down wg0
rm -rf /etc/wireguard/clients

nano /etc/wireguard/wg0.conf
# here you should change config to your settings
wg-quick up wg0
curl ifconfig.me # to be sure your IP has been changed
```

I have PuTTY logs turned off, so can't give more information.

Comment: Decent self-solved question.